# Select and update in one stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a select stored procedure and I am trying to make it so the results it bring down it also updates a column called `Downloaded` and marks those rows as downloads.

For example, I pull down 10 rows those 10 rows I also want to update the `Downloaded` column to true all in the same stored procedure. Is this possible?

This is my sp so far, it pulls down the data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeads]
@DateTo datetime = null,
@DateFrom datetime = null
AS
    SELECT name
         , lastname
         , title
         , company
         , address
         , address2
         , city
         , [state]
         , zip
         , country
         , stamptime

    FROM
        lead
    where
         ((@DateTo is null AND @DateFrom IS null) or (stamptime BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the question, but `UPDATE lead SET Downloaded=TRUE WHERE ((@DateTo is null AND @DateFrom IS null) or (stamptime BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom))` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing on vulkanino's comment answer, something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeads]
@DateTo datetime = null,
@DateFrom datetime = null
AS
    UPDATE  
        lead 
    SET     
        Downloaded = 1 
    WHERE   
        ((@DateTo is null AND @DateFrom IS null) or (stamptime BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom))

    SELECT name
         , lastname
         , title
         , company
         , address
         , address2
         , city
         , [state]
         , zip
         , country
         , stamptime

    FROM
        lead
    where
         ((@DateTo is null AND @DateFrom IS null) or (stamptime BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom))
```

Answer (score 13):

You can simply `OUTPUT` the updated rows;

```
UPDATE lead
  SET Downloaded = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.* 
  WHERE ((@DateTo is null AND @DateFrom IS null) or (stamptime BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom))
```

This updates, then returns the updated rows in a single statement.

Comment: I used this solution with DELETED.* (instead of INSERTED.*) to return the _orginal_ field values i.e. the values before the UPDATE was applied.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to use an OUTPUT statement with the UPDATE.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/

```
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE
(
    name <type>
    , lastname <type>
    , title <type>
    , company <type>
    , address <type>
    , address2 <type>
    , city <type>
    , state <type>
    , zip <type>
    , country <type>
    , stamptime <type>
)

UPDATE a
SET a.Downloaded = 1
OUTPUT Inserted.name, Inserted.lastname, Inserted.title, etc. INTO @TEMPTABLE
FROM lead a
WHERE ((@DateTo IS NULL AND @DateFrom IS NULL) OR (a.stamptime BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom))

SELECT * FROM @TEMPTABLE
```